# Looping Through a certain range with an If clause

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement

I am pretty new to coding and wrote a bit of code which doesn't work and I understand why, but can't figure out a way to solve it.
What I want to do is that my code checks each cell in column B what number is displayed and then fills in the according string in column E. My Problem is that my Loop doesn't work, because I probably should use the "for each" Loop or not? and that I can't figure out how to do my ifclause without using Ranges but instead cells.
Thank you for your time and help!

```
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To 1000
    Range ("E" & x)
        If Range("B2") = 6002 Then
            Range("E2") = "Gehälter " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6003 Then
            Range("E2") = "Üst-Pauschale " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6027 Then
            Range("E2") = "Sonderzahlung " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6110 Then
            Range("E2") = "SV-DG Anteil " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6211 Then
            Range("E2") = "MVK " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6410 Then
            Range("E2") = "Dienstgeberbeitrag " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6420 Then
            Range("E2") = "Dienstgeberzuschlag " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6430 Then
            Range("E2") = "Kommunalsteuer " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6691 Then
            Range("E2") = "Km-Geld " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 7731 Then
            Range("E2") = "Reisekosten " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B2") = 6035 Then
            Range("E2") = "Sonstige Zulagen " & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016"
Else: Range("E2") = ""
End If
Next x
```

That is what it should look like!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uAaz.png)

Comment: You problem is not with the use of `For...` instead of `For Each...` but that you keep referring to row 2 in your code instead of row x. See @anastasiya Answer below. To improve your code, you should also use `Select Case`instead of `If`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To 1000
        If Range("B" & x) = 6002 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Gehälter " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6003 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Üst-Pauschale " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6027 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Sonderzahlung " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6110 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "SV-DG Anteil " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6211 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "MVK " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6410 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Dienstgeberbeitrag " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6420 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Dienstgeberzuschlag " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6430 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Kommunalsteuer " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6691 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Km-Geld " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 7731 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Reisekosten " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
        ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6035 Then
            Range("E" & x) = "Sonstige Zulagen " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
Else: Range("E" & x) = vbNullString
End If

Next x
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim x As Long, s As String

For x = 2 To 1000

    Select Case Cells(x, "B").Value
        Case 6002: s = "Gehälter"
        Case 6027: s = "Üst-Pauschale"
        'other cases....
        Case Else: s = ""
    End Select

    Cells(x, "E").Value = IIf(s <> "", s & " " & _
                             Month(Cells(x, "G").Value) & "/2016", "")

Next x
```

Answer (score 2):

You never change the rows that you are evaluating as you loop through the cells.

This will correct your code:

```
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To 1000

    If Range("B" & x) = 6002 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Gehälter " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6003 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Üst-Pauschale " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6027 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Sonderzahlung " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6110 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "SV-DG Anteil " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6211 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "MVK " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6410 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Dienstgeberbeitrag " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6420 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Dienstgeberzuschlag " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6430 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Kommunalsteuer " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6691 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Km-Geld " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 7731 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Reisekosten " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    ElseIf Range("B" & x) = 6035 Then
        Range("E" & x) = "Sonstige Zulagen " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016"
    Else: Range("E" & x) = ""
    End If
Next x
```

But I would use a Select Case statement and do this:

```
Dim x As Long
Dim MyValue As String
For x = 2 To 1000
    Select Case Range("B" & x)
        Case 6002
        MyValue = "Gehälter"
        Case 6003
        MyValue = "Üst-Pauschale"
        Case 6027
        MyValue = "Sonderzahlung"
        Case 6110
        MyValue = "SV-DG Anteil"
        Case 6211
        MyValue = "MVK"
        Case 6410
        MyValue = "Dienstgeberbeitrag"
        Case 6420
        MyValue = "Dienstgeberzuschlag"
        Case 6430
        MyValue = "Kommunalsteuer"
        Case 6691
        MyValue = "Km-Geld"
        Case 7731
        MyValue = "Km-Geld"
        Case 6035
        MyValue = "Km-Geld"
        Case Else
        MyValue = ""
    End Select

    Range("E" & x) = IIf(MyValue = "", "",  MyValue & " " & Month(Range("G" & x)) & "/2016")

Next x
```

The Select Case will make if much easier to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Select Case** to simplify your code, you might add more cases in the future.

```
Dim lrow As Long

For lrow = 2 To 1000

    Select Case Range("B" & lrow).Value
        Case 6002
            Range("E" & lrow) = "Geh?lter " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6003
            Range("E" & lrow) = "?st-Pauschale " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6027
            Range("E" & lrow) = "Sonderzahlung " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6110
            Range("E" & lrow) = "SV-DG Anteil " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6211
            Range("E" & lrow) = "MVK " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6410
            Range("E" & lrow) = "Dienstgeberbeitrag " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6420
            Range("E" & lrow) = "Dienstgeberzuschlag " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6430
            Range("E" & lrow) = "Kommunalsteuer " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6691
            Range("E" & lrow) = "Km-Geld " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 7731
            Range("E" & lrow) = "Reisekosten " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

        Case 6035
            Range("E" & lrow) = "Sonstige Zulagen " & Month(Range("G" & lrow)) & "/2016"

         Case Else
            Range("E" & lrow) = ""

    End Select

Next lrow
```

Answer (score 1):

there was a `Range("E" & x)` pending with no methods or properties to make something out of it

moreover you may want to:

- use `Option Explicit` statement that with a little extra cost of having you declare all variables pays you back with much more control over your code and reduced debugging and maintaining efforts
- use `Select Case` block which is less verbose and more readable

which results in:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim strng As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("MyWorksheet") '<--| always use fully qualified range reference (change "MyWorksheet" with your actual sheet name)
        For Each cell In .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) '<--| loop through column "B" cells from row 2 down to last non empty one
            Select Case cell.Value
                Case 6002
                    strng = "Gehälter "
                Case 6003
                    strng = "Üst-Pauschale "
                Case 6027
                    strng = "Sonderzahlung "
                Case 6110
                    strng = "SV-DG Anteil "
                Case 6211
                    strng = "MVK "
                Case 6410
                    strng = "Dienstgeberbeitrag "
                Case 6420
                    strng = "Dienstgeberzuschlag "
                Case 6430
                    strng = "Kommunalsteuer "
                Case 6691
                    strng = "Km-Geld "
                Case 7731
                    strng = "Reisekosten "
                Case 6035
                    strng = "Sonstige Zulagen "
                Case Else
                    strng = ""
            End Select
            cell.Offset(, 3).Value = strng & Month(Range("G2")) & "/2016" '<-- use 'Offset(,rowOffset, colOffset)' method to offset from a range
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```